# How to search the data by using from and to dates in php?

Tags: php, sql

How to search the data by using from and to dates using php?

Comment: "The" data? Oh, *that* data! I see. *wink wink, nudge nudge*

Comment: No, seriously, what in the world are you talking about?

Comment: You are looking for help with sql query or approach ? Question is too generalized to answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use "between"

```
SELECT data FROM tbl WHERE date BETWEEN date1 AND date2
```

since you are having two columns in your  table as you have mentioned you your comment you can have something similar to this:

EDIT:

```
$fromDate = $_POST['fromDate'];
$toDate = $_POST['toDate'];

...




$dateSql = "Select field1, field2 from someTable where fromdate >= $fromDate ";

if (isset($toDate)) {

    $dateSql = " AND todate <= $toDate";


}
```

//execute $dateSql to get records

Comment: iam having two columns from and to  if i select that dates i should the result in between those two dates or else if i give only from date it should show that date result

Answer (score 0):

Get your Date Column and Use the Post function to Get The DateFrom and DateTo by User select

```
Select * From Table1 Where DateTo='".$_POST['DateTo']."' AND DateTo <='".$_POST['DateFrom']."'
```

Comment: Noooo! If you combine unfiltered user input with SQL, your user can edit your SQL statement, into something invalid or malicious. Don't do this.

Comment: Halfer how can that happen, am missing on your point,nevertheless that was just a sample, but you can help me to solve it?

Comment: [Read this](http://bobby-tables.com/about.html) about SQL injection (it refers to a cartoon on the home page.